# Nested elements producing parse errors

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to write the following  block for a style sheet, but I keep getting a parse error for the lines involving the h2, ul, and strong elements. I'm almost positive that it's the nested curly brackets, but I'm not sure how to write the nested elements without them. Google hasn't been much help in this.

Is this an instance where an inline declaration would work better? Am I wrong in my thoughts as to what the problem is? Can anybody clue me in on what I'm missing? Thanks.

```
#hole_stats {position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 115px;
        h2 {font-size: 1em; margin: 5,0,0,0};
        ul {list-style-type: none};
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        font-size: 0.7em;
        strong {color: yellow};
        width: 120px; 
        height: 200px; 
        color: white; 
        background-color: rgb(53, 43, 48)}
```

----EDIT-----

So, in light of the comments below, the correct format will be this???

```
#hole_stats {position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 115px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        font-size: 0.7em;
        width: 120px; 
        height: 200px; 
        color: white; 
        background-color: rgb(53, 43, 48)}
#hole_stats h2 {font-size: 1em; margin: 5,0,0,0};
#hole_stats ul{list-style-type: none};
#hole_stats strong {color: yellow};
```

Comment: You can't nest selectors in plain CSS.

Comment: CSS is not nestable. `strong { color:yellow}` is an outright syntax error.

Comment: Write e.g. `#hole_stats h2 { color: black; width: 50px }`. CSS can't be nested. May have a look at *LESS* or *SASS*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS doesn't natively allow nested rules (although some CSS preprocessors, like less, do).

In pure CSS,

```
#hole_stats {position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 115px;
    h2 {font-size: 1em; margin: 5,0,0,0};
    ul {list-style-type: none};
    /* etc */
 }
```

needs to be reformulated as

```
#hole_stats {
    position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 115px;
}
#hole_stats h2 {
    font-size: 1em; margin: 5px 0 0 0; 
}
#hole_stats ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
/*  etc */
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. Saw your answer after I posted my edit. That format makes more sense now that I think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Informally speaking, the nested curly brackets *are* the problem. More formally, a CSS rule consists of a comma-separated list of selectors, a “{”, a semicolon-separated list of declarations, and a “}”. Each declaration is of the form property: value. There is no way use selectors inside the list of declarations. You need to write

```
#hole_stats {position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 115px; }
#hole_stats h2 {font-size: 1em; margin: 5,0,0,0; }
#hole_stats ul {list-style-type: none; }
```

etc. There are various tools for generating such code, but not in CSS.